# Swift Enum with multiple types

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out how to duplicate my Java Enum into Swift and i don't know if 
this is the right way.

My Enum in Java which i am trying to write in Swift:

```
public enum EnumDB {

    DATABASE_NAME("DataBase"),
    DATABASE_VERSION(1);

    private String name;
    private int value;

    private EnumDB(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private EnumDB(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

My Swift Code:

```
enum EnumDB {

    case Name,Version

    func getName() -> String{
        switch self{
        case .Name: return "DataBase"
        }
    }

    func getNumber() -> Int{
        switch self{
        case .Version: return 1
        default: return 0
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to create an Enum with multiple value types , each enum contains
   a different type?
2. unfortunately this way i can call the methods getName() and getNumber() on each Enum which is bad because i would want those methods to be presented according to the enum type.
   Enum Associative values and Raw Values didn't help 
   to conclusion what i am looking for is writing an enum that his values can contains different types.

thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can definitely have an `enum` with associated values of different types, which I think can give you what you're looking for. This is how I might implement your example:

```
enum EnumDB {
    case Name(String)
    case Version(Int)
}

let namedDB = EnumDB.Name("databaseName")

switch namedDB {
case .Name(let name):
    println("Database name is \(name)")
case .Version(let versionNumber):
    println("Database version is \(versionNumber)")
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but still it's making me locate a constant for the Enum which i am trying to prevent. At the end i have concluded that all i wanted are constants with different types. so i have created structs with let as static's in different types. and thats because class's don't support let as class(static) yet.

Comment: Right, it doesn't sound like you want an enum at all. Either a straight global variable or a struct with static properties should be fine.

Comment: Is it just me or anyone feels that Swift is unnecessarily complicated?